# How can we separate incoming real time data in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, stm32

I am getting real time data in matlab serially.But data is a combination of two parameters(voltage and temperature) which is alternately coming. So how can i separate and plot it.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are getting now? Is it separated by a space or other character?

Comment: @MarcosG.thanks for your response sir.Initially getting data in MATLAB in the form of char and then converted into num by using str2num command.So i am getting data seperated by space. Getting data is like:   3725 2834 3724 2836 ..... that is alternate data of voltage and temperature.

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way to do it. On top of separating the Voltage and Temperature readings, I took the liberty of reorganising your code so it create a plot one time only and later update it (instead of generating a brand new plot at every new sample).

I also package the sample reading into an anonymous function to not have to repeat code too often.

The timestamp can be obtained from the very first `tic` instruction. You do not have to add each interval one by one.

```
% Prepare the plot so you do not have to recreate it at each new sample
Time        = zeros(1,1) ;
Voltage     = zeros(1,1) ;
Temperature = zeros(1,1) ;
hvolt = plot(Time,Voltage) ; 
% only if you want to display temperature, uncomment below line
% hold on ; htemp = plot(Time,Temperature) ; hold off
ylim([3,5]);
ylabel('Voltage');
xlabel('Time');

% Define an anonymous function for reading ONE sample
readSample = @(s) str2double(char(fread(s, 5).')) ;

SampleCounter = 1 ;
StartTime     = tic ;
while 1

    % Read 2 samples (one Voltage and one Temperature)
    Voltage(SampleCounter)     = readSample(s) ;
    Temperature(SampleCounter) = readSample(s) ;
    % Readt the time
    Time(SampleCounter,1)      = toc(StartTime) ;

    % Now we acquired 2 samples (one voltage and one temperature), we can
    % refresh the display:
    set(hvolt,'XData',Time,'YData',Voltage) ;

    % only if you want to display temperature, uncomment below line
    % set(htemp,'XData',Time,'YData',Temperature) ;

    drawnow
    SampleCounter=SampleCounter+1;
end
```

Comment: thanks for your effort sir .I edited code according to you but still getting same value ,not seperated.

Comment: can you shortly explain first and second line in whil loop- Voltage(SampleCounter)     = readSample(s) ;
         Temperature(SampleCounter) = readSample(s) ; my doubt is that voltage((SampleCounter)) and Temperature(SampleCounter) will contain same value?

Comment: Well if you doubt you have to try it and see if the values are similar by yourself. I do not have an STM32 micro to try it on my side so ultimately you're the only one who can say if it works or not. The reason _I think_ it should work is: the function `readSample(s)` will always try to read the next **new** value from the serial port (the next 5 bytes containing one value). So two subsequent calls to the function should not read the same value.

Comment: thanks for your reply sir,i done it by another way.And yes,two subsequent calls to the function should not read the same value.But now i am facing another problem regarding GUI.When i run the program of GUI,it shows graph in matlab instead of GUI.so any solution over it sir?

Comment: There is certainly a solution for the GUI display but this is a completely different question. If you can't find the problem yourself you can ask a _new_ question on this site. Try to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your next question.

Comment: thank you sir.As i new to this environment ,i don't know about that.